# Can anyone tell me in mysql How to display employee names whose name DO NOT start with alphabet A?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner so please help me.

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT`, `WHERE`.  This is really very basic.  You should make an attempt.

Comment: Google *SQL tutorial*.

Comment: Any query you have tried so far? pls Attach it. and which DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you need to combine in this case.

Because you didn't provide enough information in your question we have to guess what you mean by name.  I'm going to assume that you have a single name column, but that would be unusual.

With strings, to match a character column that is not an exact match, you need to use LIKE which allows for wildcards.

You also need to negate the match, or in other words show things that are NOT (something).

First to match names that START with 'A'.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE 'A%';
```

This should get you all the PEOPLE who have names that "Start with A".

Some databases are case sensitive.  I'm not going to deal with that issue.  If you were using MySQL that is not an issue.  Case sensitivity is not universal.  In some RDBMS like Oracle you have to take some steps to deal with mixed case in a column.

Now to deal with what you actually want, which is NOT (starting with A).

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name NOT LIKE 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

your question should have more detail however you can use the substr function

```
SELECT name FROM yourtable
WHERE SUBSTR(name,1,1) <> 'A'
```

complete list of mysql string functions here
[mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score -1):

**NOT REGXP operator**

**MySQL NOT REGXP** is used to perform a pattern match of a string expression expr against a pattern pat. The pattern can be an extended regular expression.

**Syntax:**

expr NOT REGEXP pat

**Query:**

`SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE emp_name NOT REGEXP '^[a]';`

or

`SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE emp_name NOT REGEXP '^a';`

Comment: I love how you simply copied the syntax from my answer 3 hours after it was posted.  I could understand how you might post a similar answer within the general time range of my answer -- it has happened to me, however, there's no excuse for replicating another answer 3 hours later!   Then you cap that off by adding a solution that involves a function that doesn't exist in mysql.  Well done LakshMi!

Comment: I might didnt see the MYSQL word in the Tittle.. and there is no tag like DBMS is MYSQL.. So i tried with other database.. :) :) Mr.gview